# How can I read a application properties file by prefix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to first print my application properties into java, then push it into a thymeleaf html page. Purpose: to allow users to edit the properties file using GET/POST. My current code will display the values key and values of the properties to the console if it is equal to something. How can I get it where it would only extract specific and multiple prefixes?

**Code/Attempt**

```
public class ReadPropertiesFile {

    public static void readProp() {

        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(ReadPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));

            Enumeration enuKeys = prop.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = prop.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println(key + "= " + value);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //System.out.print("System cannot find file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.print("System cannot find file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example application.properties**

```
prefix.foo = bar@!car@!war@!scar
prefix.cool = honda@!toyota@lexus
some.feed = live@!stream@!offline
some.feed = humans@!dogs@!cat
noprefix = dont@!print@!me
host = host1@!host2@!host3
```

To be able to just print all values of prefix and some.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple prefix?

Comment: Probably, you're asking about spring-boot? Then I suggest to add this tag to the question.

Comment: @Coder in application.properties you see the prefix.(name) or some.(name). I want to write a java code that can extract these keys based on the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ReadPropertiesFile {


public static void readProp() {

 try {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(ReadPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));

    Enumeration enuKeys = prop.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = prop.getProperty(key);
                if (key.startsWith("prefix") || key.startsWith("some")) {
                    System.out.println(key + "= " + value);
                }
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //System.out.print("System cannot find file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //System.out.print("System cannot find file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Is this what you want? Just print keys that start with "prefix" or "some"?

Comment: Is there any solutions with only annotation like @Value ?